Read and interpret mifare 4k data
How can I interpret the data on my mifare 4k (14443-a) card? My goal is to be able to read and understand the data, but the card seems to work under a specific communication between it and the valid reader. I would like to decipher this communication.
When I try to translate to ascii I just get random characters. See the example:

| sector 03 / 0x03 | ascii
----+------------------------------------------ -------+-----------------
12 | 00 08 73 80 82 22 00 70 E1 F7 E7 DD E0 4C 4A B7 | ..s..".p.....LJ.
13 | 00 80 60 00 40 1B 80 00 00 08 AF 9F 18 00 00 00 | ..`.@...........
14 | 22 BE 75 C2 A0 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 B3 A8 | ".u.............
15 | 00 00 00 00 00 00 F7 8F 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 | ................


I tried to use the card and observe which sectors changed, but I didn't get anything very useful in my analysis. See below:

| sector 03 / 0x03                                | ascii
----+-------------------------------------------------+-----------------
12 | 00 0D 56 40 82 22 00 7C 2E 26 53 81 2B 1D 34 6A | ..V@.".|.&S.+.4j
13 | 00 C0 60 00 80 33 40 00 00 08 B0 1B F0 00 00 00 | ..`..3@.........
14 | 22 C0 67 42 E0 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 C5 2F | ".gB.........../
15 | 00 00 00 00 00 00 F7 8F 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 | ................


I have access to all keys and access to all sectors, and I can also print the data. My goal is to understand them.
I'm currently studying the access bits in the trailer sector, but I don't think I'm going in the right direction. What can I do next?

You can store whatever you want on there.  It's like a thumb drive.  What makes you think there's something specific on your card?

It's my transport card.

Then the contents are proprietary to your transport card provider.  There's no centralized standard for that.  You HAVE to know that they are designed to be hack-proof.  There are one-time security tokens on there that get validated at the central server.  If you modify them, it'll be void, and it's possible to incur charges of fraud.
